# Serving file for download. Browser ignores filename and uses "file.nothing" instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, browser, download

My application has a blazor page that calls an API function to generate a report and serve that report to the browser for downloading.

For this, I am using the `ControllerBase.File` method, specifying the suggested filename.

The browser successfully begins the download, but ignores the suggested filename. Instead, giving "file.nothing"

I have seen this behaviour in both Chrome and Firefox.

Minimal reproducable example

```
[HttpPost("report/level2/deliverable")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateLevel2DeliverableReport()
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is some text");
    string filename = "test.txt";
    return File(bytes, "text/plain", filename);
}
```

In the real-world situation, I have experienced the same problem returning Word Documents and Zip files, with their respective content types.

[image: Save As Dialog]

HTTP Response as captured by Postman
[image]

The content-disposition (which is hard to read in the image) is

```
attachment; filename=test.txt; filename*=UTF-8''test.txt
```

Does anybody have any thoughts on why the browser is ignoring the filename?

Comment: Can you share code of `GetContentType` method? Did you double check the filename while debugging the code?

Comment: I have added the additional code. I have checked and confirmed that the filename variable has the value that I intend.

Comment: Specifically, the filename will either be "DeliverableReport.docx" or "DeliverableReport.zip".

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance and [edit] question accordingly. In particular replace all variables with constant values that represent your case. Make sure that those values indeed cause the issue to happen (99% people flat out lie about the values of variables in the code, I'm sure you are not one of those... but it is easier to see it directly in the question). Also show headers of the HTTP response captured with browser's dev tools or Fiddler (or whatever you like to use for that).

Comment: Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing.
I thought the download was being spawned by the line

```
return File(bytes, "text/plain", filename);
```

But it turns out, the API call was wrapped in some javascript code that pulled the filename out of the HTTP header using regex and started the download.
If the regex match failed it was hard-coding the filename to "file.nothing"
No wonder my google searches for "file.nothing" were all in vain.

There was an issue with the regex which has been fixed by a colleague and all is now well in the universe.